# cant reach static files django-react

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, static-files

I am trying to deploy a Django-React to elastic beanstalk
the deploy shows as successfull but only gives me a white empty page,(api calls work properly ).

Inspecting /var/log/nginx/error.log shows:

```
2020/08/06 02:58:06 [error] 4461#0: *11 open() "/var/app/current/staticbundle.js" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

So I understand it tries to find the bundle.js but on a wrong path,which I dont know how to fix and should look like this:

```
/var/app/current/static/bundle.js
```

I thought it wasn't building properly the static folder , but it does and it ends up like this:

```
current
   
│
└───static
│   │   bundle.js
│   │   index.html
│   
└───...
```

this is my project settings

1. Django side:

1.1 settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

1.2 urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('backend.urls')),
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),

]
```

1.3 django.config

```
    option_settings:
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
        WSGIPath: cerbero.wsgi
    
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
        /static/: static/
    container_commands:
      01_node_install:
        command: "curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash - && sudo yum -y install nodejs"
        ignoreErrors: false
    
      02_npm_install:
        command: "npm install"
        ignoreErrors: false
    
      03_react_collect:
        command: "npm run build"
        ignoreErrors: false
```

2.WebPack side:
- webpack.config.js

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  entry: './frontend/src/index.js',
  watch : false,
  devtool : 'source-map',
  output : {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './',
    inline: true,
    hot: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './frontend/templates/frontend/index.html',
        filename : './index.html',
        minify: false
    })
  ]
};
```

- index.html

```
<!doctype html>

{%load static %}

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cerbero</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="app"></div>
    <script src = "{% static '/bundle.js' %}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I really cant tell if the problem belongs to django , webpack or react

Comment: Can you try without `aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles`? `/static` is by default considered static, so no reason to overwrite it.

Comment: didn't solve the error and the message is the same,but thanks for the info

Comment: could be probably resolved by setting [baseUrl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('backend.urls')),
    re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),

]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Could you also explain your answer

Comment: Could you please explain what this does or what imports it uses?